# Key choice for brass instruments

Tags: composition, brass, arranging

I've been told several times that brass instruments prefer to play in keys with flats, rather than sharps. As a trumpet player myself, I cannot relate to this preference. E major is just as easy or hard as A flat major. I interpreted it as being the playing key, not the concert key.

I'll take that the preference is true, since I've heard it from several trustworthy sources, but why is that? I have several hypotheses:

1. Tradition. Bands (brass bands especially?) usually play in keys with flats, therefore that is what the players are used to, and more comfortable with. But how did the tradition start?
2. Intonation. The construction of valve instruments make the intonation better in keys with flats. For example in A major: the low C# of the trumpet is naturally high, whereas a good intonation should have it low as the third of a major chord. I cannot think of a counterexample right now.

I welcome guess answers, but please mention that you are just guessing if you do not actually know for a fact.

Comment: Are you asking about the preference of the instruments, or their players? I always thought it was because it's easier to make a given note flat on a brass instrument, as opposed to easier to make a note sharp on a guitar. Guess, therefore comment.

Comment: I also think your statement concerns concert key, not written. I think it simply has to do with the number of sharps or flats, and since many brass instruments "naturally" play in flat keys (concert!), those are the easiest and sound the best. See here: [Good keys / Bad keys](http://www.musicarrangers.com/star-theory/p21.htm)

Comment: My first reaction was that they meant concert key, but these sources replied that they did mean playing key.

Comment: @Gauthier This preference has to do with the fundamental resonant frequency of the instrument. For trombone and tuba (non-C non-transposing instruments, Bb is first position (tbn.) and can be open for tuba (BBb Tuba), for trumpet, Bb is open as well. Since the open, resonant frequency of the instrument is set in a "flat" key, music written in flat keys will sound more resonant than music written in keys that doesn't naturally resonant with the instrument (E major), thus, brass players see more music written in flat keys, thus, brass players favor flat keys. Sharp keys are harder to tune also.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes: this assumes concert key. I am talking about playing key. "Sharp keys are harder to tune" is very much of interest, could you develop this?

Comment: @Gauthier Trumpet is the only brass instrument you need to transpose, and even then, trumpets very commonly read in flat keys. As I mentioned in my other comment, sharp keys are harder to tune because those keys don't naturally resonate with the fundamental of the instrument. Thus, since you're fighting the natural tendency of the instrument, which resonates more freely in flat keys, tuning intervals and pitches in sharp keys will be more difficult. Also, FWIW, much band music is written in flat keys while much orchestral music is written in sharp keys - it's easier for the strings.

Comment: @jjmusicnotes? Only instrument, how about French horn, tubas? I'm not sure why flat keys resonate better with the fundamental of the (open?) instrument? Why would written Bb major (one whole tone below open) resonate better than A major (one and a half tone), and A major worse than Ab major?

Comment: @Gauthier Oh! I *completely* forgot about horns!! Yes, obviously horns are included as transposing instruments. Tubas are non-transposing. Yes, even if the tuba is F, Eb, Bb, or C, none of them transpose. With the exception of C tubas, flat keys resonate more fully because of the open tube. Because most brass instruments are pitched in flat keys (tpt, horn, tbn, euph, most tubas) they use *less* tubing when playing in flat keys, thus, the intonation is better and the instrument resonates more freely. With brass instruments, the more tubing you add, the more out of tune / stuffy the sound goes.

Comment: @Gauthier For example, on a CC tuba, F and Bb scales most just use 1st, 2nd, and open valve combinations creating a very open, resonant sound. A major on the other hand uses no open valves. It's still a very friendly key, but less so than F or Bb. On my tuba, Db is just a very stuffy key. Obviously, you can play devil's advocate with enharmonics (Db/C# or Gb/F#), but the reasoning for flats used here may be more psychological than acoustic. Putting the keys in flat can make people think of "darker" sounds or reduce key-signature anxiety. As a friend of mine said, "A# is *not* the same as "Bb".

Comment: Reading all the theory about resonance makes me ask the question - is it not possible to make some of these brass instruments of a slightly different length/bore, so as to allow them to play more in tune in sharp keys? Or is it that we're just too far down the line, (too many standard ones exist), and it would only be an academic type excercise?

Comment: @tim, the horns sound best in their open position, and the more valve tubing added, the worst they sound. I guess it has to do with where vibration nodes and bellies appear on the instrument. As soon as you add a valve, the shape of the instrument becomes more complex, nodes are at suboptimal places, and the instrument sounds worse. I guess you could make an instrument optimized for the all valves in position, though. But the shape of the tube being less "natural" than open, I suppose the all-pressed position on that wouldn't sound as nice as current instruments in open.

Comment: @Gauthier - what I meant was - if a trumpet, for example, was made so open it was D rather than Bb, surely it would sound better in that key - but not so good in Bb?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding to the narrative in other answers,
here is a chart that might help further explain why brass players
tend to prefer sheet music written in keys with flats.
As is shown, written keys that exclude the
“worst-to-play usual notes” (elaborated below)
on common brass instruments (except French horn)
are overwhelmingly keys with flats.
This is especially true for almost all lower-brass parts,
in which even the written-and-concert key of C, with no flats,
includes the worst-to-play notes for all but C tuba and triggered trombone.

The specific keys mentioned in the
question as being equally playable on
B♭ trumpet—written keys
E and A♭ —serve
well to demonstrate this chart.
The row for B♭ trumpet recognizes
the note scored as C♯ or D♭ as the most troublesome to play,
so keys with at most 1 sharp or 3 flats
are likely to be favored because they exclude C♯/D♭.
The aforementioned keys of E and A♭, however,
contain 4 sharps and 4 flats, respectively,
and thus include C♯/D♭ and are equally disfavored here.
If you are comfortable with music in these keys,
you are no doubt an experienced musician.
Not only are both keys relatively difficult to play
but trumpet music in A♭
(concert key G♭) is also quite rare.

```
                                                                   Written keys WITHOUT
                                                Worst-to-play         worst-to-play
  Name of        Version of      Open key         usual note           usual note
 instrument      instrument    ------------    ----------------     ------------------
  on score       considered    Con-   Writ-    Writ-    Valves/     How many  How many
                               cert    ten      ten    position      sharps    flats

F French horn      4-valve      F      C       G#/Ab     2-3         2,1  0  1,2
 Bb Trumpet        3-valve      Bb     "       C#/Db    1-2-3          1  0  1,2,3
Baritone T.C.         "         "      "         "        "            1  0  1,2,3
Eb Mellophone         "         Eb     "         "        "            1  0  1,2,3
Alto/Tenor horn       "         "      "         "        "            1  0  1,2,3
    Tuba            C tuba      C      "         "    1-2-3, 2-4       1  0  1,2,3
    Tuba           Eb tuba      Eb     Eb       E/Fb      "          6,7       2,3,4,5,6
    Tuba           Bb tuba      Bb     Bb       B/Cb      "            7     1,2,3,4,5
Baritone horn      4-valve      "      "         "        "            7     1,2,3,4,5
  Euphonium           "         "      "         "        "            7     1,2,3,4,5
Baritone horn      3-valve      "      "         "      1-2-3          7     1,2,3,4,5
  Euphonium           "         "      "         "        "            7     1,2,3,4,5
  Trombone        slide only    "      "         "       7th           7     1,2,3,4,5
  Trombone        F trigger     "      "    C#/Db,F#/Gb  5th              0  1,2,3
```

“Worst-to-play usual note”
is an ad hoc designation
likely to find agreement among many players due to some of these factors:

• 
  The note is in the range usually scored for the instrument.

• 
  With 3 valves but no fingered slide,
  timbre is compromised when a note is lipped into tune.

• 
  With 3 valves and a fingered tuning slide,
  coordinating the slide quickly is difficult.

• 
  With an in-line 4th valve, pinkie-vs-ring-finger agility
  is anatomically hampered.

• 
  With an opposite-hand 4th valve, coordinating the hands quickly is difficult.

• 
  On a trombone, a quick slide excursion is a gymnastic feat.

• 
  French horn players have a right to complain too.

Admittedly:  

• 
  Some fingering/position sequences and almost-worst notes
  play circumstantial roles as well.

• 
  Some rarer fingerings/positions are worse than those shown,
  but tend to also avoid flat keys.

• 
  A trombone's 7th position is the worst of the worst.
  An F attachment/trigger alleviates this.

• 
  As French horn typically plays high in its range,
  its usual worst fingering is relatively benign.

Have another usual note that you least favor
or instrument that would help to mention?
Please comment or edit.

<sub>This comes from a community band and orchestra member
who fills for whatever non-percussion parts are needed during rehearsals,
playing the most appropriate brass instruments
that happen to be along or available.</sub>

Comment: Excellent answer!  It's worth noting that the octave makes a difference in the "awkwardness" of a key.  On a trombone, a B♮2 has to be played in 7th position (without an F attachment), but a B♮3 can be played in 4th position and a B♮4 is usually played in 2nd position.  This means that a piece in D major (say) is easier to play on the trombone if it doesn't go much below G3.

Comment: Also, a related aside:  as a trombonist, I harbor a grudge against Aaron Copland for how he wrote the last movement of his Third Symphony.  The trumpets get to do the "Fanfare for the Common Man" theme in B♭, with lots of nice open fingerings.  Then the trombones have to play it in B♮.

Comment: Thank you for the difference an octave can make, @Michael Seifert. Thank you for playing trombone! And curse you, Copland, I never suspected that a composer would write a trombone passage in B♮. Was it because this instrument sounds broader in the long throw?  (Also _praise_ you, Copland, for other reasons.)

Comment: Can you add the F tuba please?

Comment: Dear @Elements in Space , F Tuba is my alter ego.  Will add details to post after  analysis.  For now, refer to F horn.

Answer (score 7):

Most wind instruments transpose in a way that adds sharps.  Horn and English horn are in F (add 1 sharp); trumpets, and half of the clarinets and saxes in Bb (add 2 sharps), and the other clarinets and saxes in Eb (add 3 sharps).  The low brass reads concert pitch, but tenor trombones and euphoniums are actually Bb instruments as well.  Bassoons are sort of in F by this same logic.  Tubas come in C, but also in each of the 3 listed transpositions.  Aside from some very esoteric instruments, nothing transposes the other way.

So if, for whatever key you choose for your composition, the winds are mostly adding sharps, then flat keys are friendlier.  Concert C puts trumpets in D and alto saxes in A.  So while E major might seem like a perfectly reasonable key for strings or piano, your trumpets end up in F# and alto saxes in C#.  Of course, a good player should be able to play in any key, but it's just not as easy.

Furthermore, brass instruments work by adding tubing to lower the pitch, so unless you're already at the bottom of the partial, you can always flatten a note.  But on trumpet, even just C -> C# or G -> G# is crossing over a break, going from the highest note of one partial into the bottom of the next.  And then there are the tuning issues you already mentioned.

Comment: I like the concept 'adds sharps'. Makes it easy to understand. 'Takes away flats' would work if the key is already a flat key. Same thing really.

Comment: I am on page with that concept, but I am sure my references did mean playing key.

Comment: I'm not sure about your "crossing breaks" reasoning. I understand that you mean that playing G to G# jumps from one partial to another, but we're talking keys here. You have either a G or a G#. If it's a G you have such a break to the A (or Ab), if it's a G# you have such a break to the F#.

Answer (score 2):

> I interpreted it as being the playing tonality, not the concert tonality.

There is your mistake.  As a comment *about* brass players, this statement is for the benefit of those *not* playing the instrument and consequently is about concert pitch.

Indeed, it does not make much sense to speak about *playing* pitch in this context since the *playing* key differs even within the brass section.

Comment: As @MattPuman wrote, most of them are still adding sharps. Besides, my question is about preferred keys, a given arrangement might fail to make everybody happy.

Comment: The wording of the question has changed from using "tonality" to "key".

Answer (score 2):

All answers (and their up-voters) up till now fail to take into account this essential parameter: I am talking about playing key, not concert key. A comment from @jjmusicnotes made me think of this possibility (a wild guess):

For the same amount of flats or sharps, more flat keys feature the open C and G.

F major or G major have both C and G, so they're not relevant.

2: Bb major has both C and G, while D major misses the open C (it has the middle E though, which Bb major lacks).

3: Eb major has C and G, A major has neither.

4: Ab major has both, E major has none.

5: Db major has C, not G, B major has no open tone.

The hypothesis is that the keys that feature open tones are preferred because the instruments resonate better on open tones.

Answer (score 1):

This seems much more of a worry to composers/arrangers than to brass players!  OK, ask for a preference, we'll come up with one.  But it's not important.

There are two notes on trumpet that require all three valves to be depressed.  Written low C# and the F# below.  All but the cheapest student instrument have the technology to extend the 3rd (and sometimes 1st) valve slides so as to play them in tune.  They aren't hard to play.  But that range of the trumpet has neither the brightness of a trumpet's higher notes or the appealing flatulence of a trombone's low register.  Write it if you want, but know what you'll be getting.

Comment: It is from the viewpoint of the arranger that I am asking the question. It is important for the arranger to know what brass players prefer, if given the choice, the arranger could make the one that is easy on the players. I play the trumpet, and when arranging for trumpets I do try to avoid the low C#, because even if it's manageable, depending on the trumpeters' level, its intonation doesn't often get the attention it should. I am guilty of that as a player myself.

Comment: Interesting that we (as I suspect most trumpertrs would) are referring to that note as C#, not Db.

Comment: Which partial a tone builds on is nothing you think about when you play, especially if you've been playing since you were a kid. C# comes earlier than Db in the list of key signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the test - ask a bunch of brass players to first sight-read a passage with n *sharps* in the key signature and then a different passage of similar difficulty with n *flats* in the key signature. Count the number of errors for each performance and collate the results.

My expectation (contrary to the received wisdom quoted in the OP) is that the accuracy would fall as the n increases, but would not depend on whether the key contained sharps or flats.

My feeling is that brass players, in common with most other musicians, prefer keys with *few* sharps or flats. Keys with lots of sharps or flats aren't innately harder to play - but because they often get less practice they're less familiar and so don't fall automatically under the fingers.

Answer (score 1):

My preference ,as a tuba player, I can't really read more than two sharps. Yet I can read down to all flats fairly easy. Its just much more common to see flats than sharps. This is of bably likely do the jump from bass clef to treble. I only have a sharp if say like a sax has four sharps.